# Floating Strike Geometric Averaged Asian Option Pricing

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, geometric-brownian

How can I use the risk neutral evaluation to price an asian option with floating strike using the continuous geometric average? I have tried searching for ways to do it but have found almost nothing.

Comment: Espen G. Haug. The Complete Guide To Option Pricing Formulas. Mc-
Graw Hill, 2007.
P. Zhang. Exotic options: A Guide to the Second Generation Options.
Singapore: World Scientific, 1998.

Comment: Thanks!, I have posted a solution please edit as required. @Nick

Comment: could you please take a look at the edit, I have some issues deriving @Nick

Comment: Given the edit to your question, your answer below makes it a bit difficult for a reader to follow. Perhaps it would be better if you posted a new question for the one in the edit itself.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick suggested, looking Espen G. Haug. The Complete Guide To Option Pricing Formulas. Mc- Graw Hill, 2007. P. Zhang. Exotic options, equation 4.105 shows a symmetric relation between a floating strike call and a fixed strike put. The latter is straightforward to calculate and using the substitutions for a fixed put with $S=S,X=S,T=T,r=0,b=-r,v=\sigma$ for a stock price with no dividends we obtain:

$V^{call}_{floating}(S,t=0) =  SN(-d_2)-Se^{\frac{-T}{2}\left(r+\frac{\sigma ^2}{6}\right)}N(-d_1)$

using:
$$d_1 = \frac{\frac{-1}{2}(r-\frac{1}{6} \sigma^2)T}{\sigma \sqrt\frac{T}{3}}$$
$$d_2 = d_1 -\sigma \sqrt \frac{T}{3}$$

And therefore:
$$V^{put}_{floating}(S,t=0) =  Se^{\frac{-T}{2}\left(r+\frac{\sigma ^2}{6}\right)}N(d_1)- SN(d_2)$$